# How to toggle a single element and make other elements react

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
body,
hmtl {
  background- color: black;
}

.text {
  color: Black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  background- color: blue;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.change .bar2 {
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: -100px;
  border- radius: 100px;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 200px;
  opacity: 1! important;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.change .text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1">
      <p class="details"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

I want to be able to toggle just the first element `.bar1` and have the other two react in the way specified. I don't want user to be able to toggle bottom two elements `.bar2` `.bar3` but I still want them to react when `.bar1` is pressed.

I tried moving the `a` attribute, but that didn't work as I was able to toggle the `.bar1` but `.bar2` and `.bar3` didn't react. They are in a container so do I need separate containers and if so how do I link them? At the moment you can only toggle all three at once.

Comment: why have everything in a tag `<a href ..` it's not really a good idea?!

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Why not and what do I do instead

Comment: because this tag is dedicated to refer to a link and it detects the mouse click automatically

Comment: So please see desktop at https://4309.co.uk to see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: are you kidding me? there are 2300 lines of code right on the main page and without counting the different css or js links

Comment: :-) At the moment the user can click on any element to change the design. I want them only to be able to click on `B`. is it possible? The code above  should give me the principle if i can work out how to modify it to achieve what I want...feel free to try for yourself... It's interactive... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the event listener to the container, but only match if the event.target is the element you want.
There are of course other ways to achieve this by storing variables and attaching event listeners differently, and entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Using onclick as you have in your example:

```js
function myFunction(this1, x) {
  if(x.target.matches('.bar1'))
    this1.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
body,
hmtl {
  background- color: black;
}

.text {
  color: Black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  background- color: blue;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.change .bar2 {
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: -100px;
  border- radius: 100px;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 200px;
  opacity: 1! important;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.change .text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this,event)">
    <div class="bar1">
      <p class="details"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Using addEventListener

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  if(x.target.matches('.bar1'))
    this.classList.toggle('change');
}

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

```css
body,
hmtl {
  background- color: black;
}

.text {
  color: Black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  background- color: blue;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.change .bar2 {
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: -100px;
  border- radius: 100px;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 200px;
  opacity: 1! important;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.change .text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bar1">
      <p class="details"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
</a>
```